# The right menu has closed and I cant reopen it for some reason

Tags: interface

[image]I have some problems with the interface,to be more specific the right menu has closed and I cant reopen it for some reason.

Does anyone know how to reopen it?

Comment: Not enough information! Which right menu are you talking about? Post an image of Blender's screen into your question: In Blender, use the Window > Save Screenshot menu. Then you cna insert the image into your question by editing your question and following this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)